# Redirect urls with question mark and other parameters in htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I want to redirect pages like:

```
/category-name/post-name.html?id=1234
```

To:

```
/category-name/1234-post-name.html
```

How can do this using `htaccess`?

What I have tried:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=(.*)$
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^.]+)\.html$ /$1/%1-$2\.html [L,R=301]
```

But it is a continuous redirect.

Comment: You are doing everything wrong check my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use these rules in your site root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

# external redirect from actual URL to pretty one
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)\?id=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1/%3-%2? [R=301,L,NE]

# internal forward from pretty URL to actual one
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/([^-]+)-([\w-]+)/?$ $1/$3?id=$2 [L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

Make sure the url is root url

Example:-

```
www.foo.com/category-name/post-name.html
```

It will only work if the project url is same as that of the above.

```
www.foo.com/blog/category-name/post-name.html
```

This won't work you need to update the RewriteBase url accordingly l.

This is the conditions

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %(REQUEST_FILENAME) !-f
RewriteCond %(REQUEST_FILENAME) !-d
```

RewriteRule here

```
RewriteRule ^category-name/([0-9]+)-post-name$ /category-name/post-name.html?id=$1 [L]
```

This should work..

Comment: Instead of `category-name` and `post-name` could be anything. The page should end with `.html`. I need to redirect from `?id=number` to `number-post-name`, not reverse.

Comment: Thats what my code does. Convert foo.com/cat/post?id=12 into foo.com/cat/12-post

Comment: I DON'T want to repeat the rule for each post and category. I want be automated. That's why I asked. Thank you!

Comment: I don't know what is Wrong with my regex.